# Where are the VAPI for the C standard library?

Tags: c, vala

I was trying to study some of the VAPI that are bundled with the `valac` compiler, at least according to how it's packaged under Ubuntu, and I can't find the VAPI for the C standard library, I'm particularly curious about getting this VAPI file because I would like to start with something simpler and something that I know better than all the others libraries.

So where I can find the VAPI file for the C standard library ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vala uses glib as its standard library, so the answer is glib-2.0.vapi.  Where glib functionality overlaps with standard library functionality we typically use the glib version for better portability, but there are also many standard library functions in glib-2.0.vapi which don't actually go through glib.  For example, most of the GLib.FileStream methods are standard C functions--they are actually pretty well supported everywhere, so glib doesn't have to reimplement them.

posix.vapi contains some C standard library functions, but they really shouldn't be used.  They are there mainly because Vala used to support a POSIX profile which allowed you to compile code which didn't use GLib.  When using the POSIX profile, posix.vapi was used much like how glib-2.0.vapi is used now--mixing POSIX with standard C calls.

Comment: any specific mention to which C standard is actually used by vala ? C99 ?

Comment: Vala compiles to C89, and glib is also meant for systems with only C89 (remember, MSVC still doesn't have full C99 support) so it usually provides replacements for C99-specific functions.  That said, a C99 function or two may have snuck into the VAPI--if the choice is between the C99 function and nothing we would rather just bind it.

Answer (score 3):

You can find lots of C standard library functions in the Posix namespace.

http://www.valadoc.org/#!api=posix/Posix

The VAPI file is called `posix.vapi` which is part of the `valac-0.24-vapi` (where 0.24 is the version number of the vala compiler) Debian package.